# Android logic issue

Tags: android, null, logic

I am currently learing Android and writing an app to assist me with my job.  I have been using this excellent website for quite a while now and, genrally after a lot of research, it has helped me get my head round most concepts.

Thought I would ask my first question as I am sure it will have a simple answer - the logic in the following statement is not working as expected:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, final int pos, final long id){

    Cursor cursor = (Cursor) rmDbHelper.fetchInspection(id);
    String inspectionRef = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(
            RMDbAdapter.INSPECTION_REF));
    String companyName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(
            RMDbAdapter.INSPECTION_COMPANY));

    if (inspectionRef == null && companyName == null){
        inspectionDialogueText = "(Inspection Reference unknown, Company Name unknown)";    
    }
    else if (inspectionRef != null && companyName == null) {
        inspectionDialogueText = "(" + inspectionRef + ", Company Name unknown)";
        }
    else if (inspectionRef == null && companyName != null) {
        inspectionDialogueText = "(Inspection Reference unknown, " + companyName + ")";
    }
    else {
        inspectionDialogueText = "(" + inspectionRef + ", " + companyName + ")";
    }
```

I'm not sure if I should be using null or "" in the if statements but either way it doesn't work as it just prints inspectionRef and companyName regardless of if they contain anything..

Sorry if I'm just being a dunce!

Many thanks,

David

Comment: you should also check for isEmpty after == null check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android has a nice [utility method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html) to check for both empty (`""`) and `null` `Strings`

```
TextUtils.isEmpty(str)
```

it's just `(str == null || str.length() == 0)` but it saves you a bit of code.

If you want to filter out strings that contain only whitespace (`"    "`) you can add a `trim()`

```
if (str == null || str.trim().length() == 0) { /* it's empty! */ }
```

You can replace `str.length() == 0` with `str.isEmpty()` if you are using Java 1.6

Your code could for example be replaced by

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(inspectionRef)){
    inspectionRef = "Inspection Reference unknown";
}
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(companyName)){
    companyName = "Company Name unknown";
}
// here both strings have either a real value or the "does not exist"-text
String inspectionDialogueText = "(" + inspectionRef + ", " + companyName + ")";
```

---

If you use that piece of logic all over your code you could put it in some utility method

```
/** returns maybeEmpty if not empty, fallback otherwise */
private static String notEmpty(String maybeEmpty, String fallback) {
    return TextUtils.isEmpty(maybeEmpty) ? fallback : maybeEmpty;
}
```

and use it like

```
String inspectionRef = notEmpty(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(
        RMDbAdapter.INSPECTION_REF)), "Inspection Reference unknown");
String companyName = notEmpty(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(
        RMDbAdapter.INSPECTION_COMPANY)), "Company Name unknown");

inspectionDialogueText = "(" + inspectionRef + ", " + companyName + ")";
```

Comment: Hi Zapl, thanks for the detailed reply.  I will have a go with this tonight. Would add a tick to your anwser but I don't have the rep yet! Cheers, Dave.